# Javascript time to PHP time

Tags: php, javascript, date, time

I have a time value in javascript for example 11:30:00.

```
 Date {Mon Oct 22 2012 11:30:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)}
```

and I passed to a php file and converted it by:

```
 $newTime = date('H:i:s', $theTime);
```

But, it return 05:36:00. What is the right way of concerting time?

Comment: try passing the date in UTC. ie: `(new Date).toJSON()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `myDate.getTime()` instead, and then divide this by 1000 since PHP deals with seconds while JavaScript deals with milliseconds.

Comment: i guess it worked. I tried this before but without dividing by 1000 that's wht it did not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to use PHP to parse the date/datetime, then you should use `strtotime()`. Something like:

```
$time = "Mon Oct 22 2012 11:30:00 GMT+0800";
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($time));
```

Which would output:

> 2012-10-22 04:30:00

This output is GMT, which you can change if required.

**EDIT:**

If you're expecting 11:30:00, then try the following:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$time = "Mon Oct 22 2012 11:30:00 GMT+0800";
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($time));
```

Comment: I tried that but it returned 1970 01:00:00 but let me try that again

Comment: Works for me - tested it for sanity!

Comment: but at first it is on 11:30 but after converting it it turns to 4:30. Is that suppose to be 11:30 not 4:30?

Comment: You can set your default timezone in PHP: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei');` which would localise it. Just set that before you echo out the date/time.

Comment: Hang on - what are you expecting? 11:30?

Comment: yup, still 11:30. Just a matter of passing it into other languages and converting it to a time format.